# ESC (flyback diode)

Tags: mosfet, pwm, flyback, gate-driving, high-current

i bulid ESC circuit based on TLP250 gate driver and IRF3205 MOSFET ,My motor works with 5V and consume about between 6 A and 8 A. the ESC circuit works well over month with software PWM frequency = 350 hz  .

After changing to hardware PWM frequency =15000 hz.
when i was working , **suddenly the flyback diode get on fire and make smoke then get roasted** .

After some tests I found what the cause of this is the high frequency of PWM , this what cause the high temperature and then roasted the diode.What happen ? do I miscalculate the flyback diode (which is 1n4001) ?

This is my ESC :
[image: c]

[image]

Comment: Where’s the schematic? If you want us to guess, then my guess is you’ve used the wrong diode.

Comment: I assume open drain. How hot did the diode get before hand > 80'C  What was motor DC R and inertia load like?  How much Power in supply?

Comment: I don't understand the first part of your question , my power supply is 5 V for motor .. and 12 V for gate driver just to open the mosfet gate with high voltage .

Comment: How long did it take to get up to full speed with your method?  Can you measure DC resistance of motor?

Comment: @Tony Stewart EE75 , If I tell the raspberry to send PWM signal to motor it goes to full speed instantly , resistance is 0.5 ohm .

Comment: Then how can you draw 30A from 5V/0.5ohm?  Your lack of clear specs is mind numbing.  Have you considered the diode capacitance when switching at 15kHz for current and 400 mOhm diode resistance when conducting 8A into motor and 5 to 20 pF for CdV/dt=I of  into the diode?  THis is why low pF fast diodes are used with high current ratings

Comment: I  don't feel you ! from where you get 30A ? I just put the multimeter and measure the resistance , and it gives 0.5 ohm . I don't know any thing about diode capacitance or what is after . all i need is explanation for what happen , why my flyback diode can't support this work at 15KHz ? and what is the solution for this (replacement of 1n4007 diode  ) ?